# What will sizeof(myArray) be?

Tags: c

Consider the following type definition and variable definition:

```
typedef char x[10];  
x myArray[5];
```

The `sizeof(myArray)` is `50`, but I don't know why? (Assume one character occupies 1 byte.)
Please explain the answer?

Comment: Erm, 5 times 10 is 50... what do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

`typedef char x[10];` defines a new type `x` as an array of 10 `char`s. So, `myArray` is an array of 5 `x`--which is an array of 10 `char`s.
That is `myArray` is actually of `char[5][10]` type; an array of `5` elements of which each element is an array of `10` `char`s.
Therefore `sizeof(myArray)` will return `50`.

Comment: will you please explain what is exactly happening in this process?

Comment: @user3756648: He did.  `myArray` is an array of five `x`'s, and each `x` is an array of 10 `char`, for a total size of 50.

Comment: @user3756648: Let's look at it the other way around; what don't you understand about it so far?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i am curious about what is happening in the first line.what if i write x c='z' in the place of second line.

Comment: @user3756648 You can't do that. x is a typedef for a char array of length 10.

Comment: @SeriousBusiness that means if i write x c; in the place of second line then c will be a char array of length 10?

Comment: @FredOverflow; That was a typo. Fixed tha.

Comment: ordering people to delete their comments; awesome

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit; Because they were obsolete :). I should understand that.

Comment: is it `myArray[5][10]` or `myArray[10][5]`   because jonathan is saying it is `x[10][5]` and @haccks is saying it is `x[10][5]`?

Comment: @user3756648; `myArray[10][5]` was a typo. See the edited answer. It is `myArray[5][10]`.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to "explain" anything, when the answer appears to be obvious. There's just no way to determine which specific detail to focus on.

You declared a typename `x` that stands for type `char [10]`. This type has size `10`.

Then you declared an object `myArray`, which consists of `5` elements of type `x`. Obviously, the size of `myArray` will be `50` (i.e. `5 * 10`).

That's all.

If this is not a sufficient explanation, you have to explain first what exactly is causing the confusion.

Comment: it is myArray[5][10] or [10][5].

Comment: @user3756648: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. Is this a question?

Comment: is it myArray[5][10] or [10][5].